# Recording multiple videos to differing file names with Raspberry Pi Camera triggered by IR Sensor

Tags: python

I am currently working on setting up my Raspberry Pi to (when triggered by an IR sensor) record twenty second videos, each to a new file.

Currently it is returning this error when movement is detected:

"*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pir_2filenametest2.py", line 57, in 
    for filename in camera.start_recording('pivid{counter:03}.h264'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable*"

I am pretty much brand new to python, so any help would be wonderful.

Here is the code:

```
# Author : Matt Hawkins
# Date   : 21/01/2013
# Import required Python libraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import picamera
# Use BCM GPIO references
# instead of physical pin numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
# Define GPIO to use on Pi
GPIO_PIR = 7
print "Wilbur Cam! (CTRL-C to exit)"
# Set pin as input
GPIO.setup(GPIO_PIR,GPIO.IN)      # Echo
Current_State  = 0
Previous_State = 0
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
try:
  print "Waiting for PIR to settle ..."
  # Loop until PIR output is 0
  while GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR)==1:
    Current_State  = 0    
  print "  Ready"     

  # Loop until users quits with CTRL-C
  while True :

    # Read PIR state
    Current_State = GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR)

    if Current_State==1 and Previous_State==0:
      # PIR is triggered
      print "  Motion detected!"
      # Record previous state
      Previous_State=1
      # Camera begins to record
      camera.resolution = (1360, 768)
      for filename in camera.start_recording('pivid{counter:03}.h264'):
        print('Captured %s' % filename)
        time.sleep(20)
        camera.stop_recording()
    elif Current_State==0 and Previous_State==1:
      # PIR has returned to ready state
      print "  Ready"
      Previous_State=0

    # Wait for 10 milliseconds
    time.sleep(0.01)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print "  Quit" 
  # Reset GPIO settings
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

[camera.start_recording](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#picamera.PiCamera.start_recording) does not return a value, it starts the recording, the first arg `output` is what the video is written to  which you could pass as a string or a file object but there is nothing to iterate over:

**start_recording(output, format=None, resize=None, splitter_port=1, **options)**

`Start recording video from the camera, storing it in output.
If output is a string, it will be treated as a filename for a new file which the video will be written to. Otherwise, output is assumed to be a file-like object and the video data is appended to it (the implementation only assumes the object has a write() method - no other methods will be called).`

So in  your case the filename is `'pivid{counter:03}.h264')`

If you want different filenames you could use something like the following:

```
i = 0  # set i to 0 outside the while
while True :    
    # Read PIR state
    Current_State = GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR)    
    if Current_State==1 and Previous_State==0:
      # PIR is triggered
      print "  Motion detected!"
      # Record previous state
      Previous_State=1
      # Camera begins to record
      camera.resolution = (1360, 768)
      camera.start_recording('pivid{}.h264'.format(i)) # pass i to str.format
      print('Captured pivid{}.264'.format(i))
      i += 1 # increase i
      time.sleep(20)
      camera.stop_recording()
```